# Filtering list of tuples - better readability

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming, scala-collections, readability

What is a good way( read better readability) to filter a list of tuples. I'm using

```
tupleList.filter(_._2).map(_._1)
```

But this does not feel readable.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much better but you can use collect:

```
tupleList.collect { case (true, x) => x }
```

and of course give x some meaningful name. If the first element is not a boolean you can even do something like:

```
tupleList.collect { case (x, y) if (cond) => y}
```

and give x and y meaningful names

Answer (score 0):

Using the equivalent with partial functions can also help:

```
tupleList.filter { case (_, snd) => snd }
         .map { case (fst, _) => fst }
```

This should improve significantly when Dotty arrives with tuple unpacking.